# LDLt factorization using SciPy's Python bindings to LAPACK

Tags: scipy, lapack

I am trying to get the LDLt factorization of a given symmetric matrix with SciPy's Python bindings to LAPACK using the `dsysv` routine which actually solves linear systems using this matrix factorization.

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg.lapack import dsysv

A = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=(5, 5))
A = (A + A.T)
b = np.random.randn(5)
lult, piv, x, _ = dsysv(A, b, lower=1)
```

Where `x` would be the solution for the above linear system and `lult` and `piv` contain information about the factorization.

How can I reconstruct LDLt from it? Sometimes negative values are contained in `piv` and from the [docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520991) I was not able to understand their meaning.

LAPACK's [sytrf](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-sytrf#72C2D4F7-4A77-4C93-8054-4A89F6FE98C4) actually computes this factorization (without solving any linear system) but it does not seem available via SciPy.

There is an example [here](http://www.hpcavf.uclan.ac.uk/softwaredoc/sgi_scsl_html/sgi_html/ch03.html) with the output I am interested in (see eq. 3-23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the required information is found in the [documentation of systrf](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-sytrf#72C2D4F7-4A77-4C93-8054-4A89F6FE98C4). But admittedly, it is a somewhat verbose.

So just give me the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg.lapack import dsysv

def swapped(i, k, n):
    """identity matrix where ith row and column are swappend with kth row and column"""
    P = np.eye(n)
    P[i, i] = 0
    P[k, k] = 0
    P[i, k] = 1
    P[k, i] = 1
    return P


# example

n = 5

A = np.random.rand(n, n)
A = (A + A.T)
b = np.random.randn(n)
lult, piv, x, _ = dsysv(A, b, lower=1)


# reconstruct L and D

D = np.zeros_like(A, dtype=float)
L = np.eye(n)

k = 0
while k < n:
    i = piv[k]

    if i < 0:
        s = 2
    else:
        s = 1

    if s == 1:
        i = i - 1
        D[k, k] = lult[k, k]  # D(k) overwrites A(k,k)
        Pk = swapped(k, i, n)
        v = lult[k+1:n, k]  # v overwrites A(k+1:n,k)
        Lk = np.eye(n)
        Lk[k+1:n, k] = v
    else:
        m = -i - 1
        D[k:k+2, k:k+2] = lult[k:k+2, k:k+2]  #  the lower triangle of D(k) overwrites A(k,k), A(k+1,k), and A(k+1,k+1)
        D[k, k+1] = D[k+1, k]  # D is symmeric
        Pk = swapped(k+1, m, n)
        v = lult[k+2:n, k:k+2]  # v overwrites A(k+2:n,k:k+1)
        Lk = np.eye(n)
        Lk[k+2:n, k:k+2] = v   

    L = L.dot(Pk).dot(Lk)

    if s == 1:
        k += 1
    else:
        k += 2

print(np.max(np.abs(A - L.dot(D).dot(L.T))))  # should be close to 0
```

The snipped above reconstructs L and D from the decomposition (it would need to be adapted to reconstruct U from an UDUt decomposition). I will try to explain below. First a quote from the documentation:

> ... additional row interchanges are required to recover U or L explicitly (which is seldom necessary).

Reconstructing L (or U) requires a number of iterations with row exchanging operations and matrix multiplication. This is not very efficient (less so when done in Python) but luckily this reconstruction is seldom necessary. So make sure you really have to do this!

We reconstruct `L` from `L = P(1)*L(1)* ... *P(k)*L(k)*...,`. (Fortran indices are 1-based). So we need to iterate k from 0 to n, obtain K and L in each step and multiply them.

`P` is a permutation matrix, defined by `piv`. A positive value of `piv` is straight-forward (`i = piv[k]`). It means that the ith and kth row/column were swapped in A before performing the operation. In this case the kth diagonal element of `lult` corresponds to the kth diagonal element of `D`. `L(k)` contains the kth column of the lower diagonal matrix - after the swapping.

A negative value of `piv` means that the corresponding element of `D` is a 2x2 block instead of just one element, and `L(k)` corresponds to two columns of the lower diagonal matrix.

Now for each step in `k` we obtain `L(k)`, apply the swapping operation `P(k)`, and combine it with the existing `L`. We also obtain the 1x1 or 2x2 block of D and correspondingly increase `k` by 1 or 2 for the next step.

---

I won't blame anyone for not comprehending my explanation. I simply wrote it down as I figured it out... Hopefully, the combination of the code snippet, the description, and the original documentation prove useful :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many of those seldom cases in practice that needed to be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

`dsysv` is the linear system solver and it does all the magic internally including calls to `dsytrf`. So for the factorization it is not needed. As kazemakase mentioned this is now available in SciPy ([PR 7941](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7941) and will appear officially in version 1.1) and you can just use the [`scipy.linalg.ldl()`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.linalg.ldl.html#scipy.linalg.ldl) to get the factorization and the permutation information of the outer factors. Actually this was the reason why `?sytrf` and `?hetrf` was added.

You can look at its source code to see how `ipiv` is sanitized.

With SciPy v.1.1 built with OpenBlas on Windows 10 machine vs. matlab using mkl, the performance is given below

[image]

Adding extra JIT-compilers on top of it probably would bring it to matlab speed. Since the ipiv handling and the factorization construction is done in pure numpy/python. Or better cythonize it if performance is the utmost importance.

Comment: Uh, nice! I didn't know about `linalg.ldl` as I was looking into this from bottom-up :)

Comment: @kazemakase Just to piggy back this opportunity, please let SciPy people what you need in terms of implementation because it is really tough to guess what should have higher priority. Sometimes it's hard to keep up with requests but if something is requested enough times it passes the threshold of *hmm, maybe we should add this now* :)

Comment: yeah, makes sense.. As far I am concerned I'm happy if something is available and if not I roll my own solution and nevermind efficiency :) Unfortunately, I'm usually not confident enough in the quality of my ad-hoc implementations to submit them as contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Updating scipy to version >= 1.0.0 should do the trick.

A wrapper to `sytrf` has been added to the master branch in mid-September, just before the [1.0.0 Beta release](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.0.0b1).
You can find the relevant [pull-request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7851) and [commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/972f3e1323d5fc9bd2b07ea4df97416ad2b5846c) on Github.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this wouldn't solve the problem of how to factor `LDLt` from `ipiv` AFAIK

Comment: @jarandaf Didn't you say that sytrf computes the factorization you need?

Comment: `dsysv` uses `sytrf` internally, but `sytrf` still uses the `ipiv` vector to encode matrix permutations (which I don't know how to get) necessary to obtain the `LDLt` factorization I am interested in. See updated question with an example of this factorization.

Comment: @jarandaf Well, I was mislead by "*...but it does not seem available via Scipy.*" because I understood it as "*if it was available the problem would be solved*" ;)